# Establishing a relation between two forms of energy

Tags: special-relativity, energy

I'll be giving a quite simple relationship between the rest energy of a body and it's kinetic energy
So..
E=mc² where E is rest energy and K.E.=1/2(mv²)
Where K.E. is kinetic energy. So the relationship can easily be seen as E=2(K.E.)/β²
Where β=v/c
Also, I've been told β is actually a thing and is used in the Lorentz factor and what could be the validity of the established relationship?

Comment: The energy for a moving particle is $\sqrt{m^2c^4+p^2c^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between an object's rest and kinetic energy is already well established.

Rest energy: $E = mc^2$

Total energy: $E = \gamma mc^2$

So an object's kinetic energy is commonly expressed as 
$E = (\gamma - 1)mc^2$. If you taylor expand that about $\beta = 0$, you'll recover $E_k = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$

Therefore the relationship between kinetic and rest energy is:

$\frac{E_{kinetic}}{E_{rest}} = \gamma - 1$

Comment: Ok, but what about the relationship that i seem to have found. Is it one and the same?

Comment: no it's not. doesn't take into account relativity